# using react js application on ubuntu

Tags: react-native, ubuntu

how to do cleanup of a react js application running on ubuntu 18.0.4 setup. we want the application to run without any CLI issues.

Answer (score 1):

Only `BAMMON` or the one who granted those privileges (a DBA?) knows *why* that user needs those privileges.

How to "fix" it?

- revoke all those privileges
- create a **role** with only one privilege, e.g. `create session`
- grant it to `bammon`
- when `bammon` says he can't do *something*, grant that privilege to role

  - `bammon` will be able to use it right away
- loop through the last steps as many times as it turns out that `bammon` needs to do something, but can't
- also, see whether lower level of privileges suits the needs, e.g. don't grant `create any procedure` but `create procedure`